# tree expression - Node setting up

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, mathematical-expressions

I am confused with a project that I study for a course.
I have to build a tree-expression, I know how the algorithm works, but I have difficulties with setting up the nodes.

The instructor gave us this class: Expression Node
Where it has 2 other subclasses: Constant Node and Operator Node?

and in the "Expression Tree class": Where am I building the tree-expression? I have a Stack with this type : Expression Node

my question is: after I assign an operator or an constant, how can I push it to the Stack, since the types are different.

i am working with C++
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply polymorphism: Push pointers ( or references ) to your nodes.
Since your stack contains elements of type "ExpressionNode", it can accept all types that derive from it ( Constant and Operator).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to boost, boost::variant is what you are looking for.
See [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html), it is OO version of union.

header file

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

stack<boost::variant<int,char>> s;
s.push('+');
s.push(1);
```